# Prolog sum of numbers not in a list

Tags: prolog

In gnu Prolog I'm trying to collect the sum of all college credits in an College Adviser program.

Currently, it returns the number of credits like such:

```
| ?- totalCredits(joe, X).

X = 3 ? ;

X = 3 ? ;

X = 3 ? ;

X = 1 ? ;

X = 3 ? ;

X = 3 ? ;

no
```

And this is that code sample:

```
totalCredits(Student, Credits) :-
    class(Class, _, _),
    creditFor(Student, Class, _),
    class(Class, _, Credits).
```

So my question is how can I sum up all of those results? I'm completely new to prolog and have only used functional languages before and so maybe I am missing something completely.

Comment: What is the second argument of `class/3`? This might influence the outcome (and invalidate the current answers).

Comment: The second argument of class is the String name of the class (for beauty purposes on printout).

Comment: Then it's fine. If the second argument would have been, .e.g the curriculum it is used for (e.g. 2 credits for CS, 1 credit for Math), then some precaution to avoid counting duplicates would have been needed.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, and I don't plan on having any functionality like that, at least programmed in such a manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [collect a list](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog033.html#toc79) of credits and then [sum](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/html_node/gprolog044.html#toc176) it:

```
totalCredits(Student, Total) :-
  findall(Credits, creditFor(Student, _Class, Credits), ListOfCredits),
  sum_list(ListOfCredits, Total).
```

**edit** after comment, a correction: join the relations!

```
totalCredits(Student, Total) :-
  findall(Credits,
    (creditFor(Student, Class, _),
     class(Class, _, Credits)), ListOfCredits),
  sum_list(ListOfCredits, Total).
```

Comment: Unfortunately creditFor contains the Student's Name, class, and grade, respectively. The credit for the class is determined by class(class name, class string name, credit).

Answer (score 0):

Use `findall` to get all the credits, then sum those.

```
findall(C, creditFor(Student, _, C), Credits),
sum(Credits, Sum).
```

(I hope I've understood the meaning of your `creditFor` predicate correctly.)

Here, `sum` is a summation predicate that I'll leave to you; it should be very similar to its functional counterpart.